# How to exclude objects from serializing based on some values witg GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I have a json structure to make from a POJO class like this -

```
 {
"arrayA":[
      {
         "arrayB":[
            {
              "arrayC":[
                  {
                     "base64String":null
                  },
                  {
                     "base64String":"base 64 value here"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, Objects in arrayC have a field named base64String. Now this base64String may be null sometimes, so while serializing the POJO to json, is there a way to check if this base64String is null and omit that particular object from serializing?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation I was able to do it myself. Answering here if someone else needs this. We need to use `JsonSerializer` provided by Gson to check for values as they are being serialized.

```
    public class SerializeFiles implements JsonSerializer<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(MyClass src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject object = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(src);
        JsonArray arrayA = object.getAsJsonArray("arrayA");
        for (JsonElement element : arrayA) {
            JsonObject objA = element.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray arrayB = insObj.getAsJsonArray("arrayB");
            for (JsonElement elementB : arrayB) {
                JsonObject objB = elementB.getAsJsonObject();
                JsonArray arrayC = objB.getAsJsonArray("arrayC");
                for(JsonElement elementC : arrayC) {
                    JsonObject objectC = elementC.getAsJsonObject();
                    if(objectC.get("base64String") == null) {
                        arrayC.remove(objB);
                    }
                }
            }
            return object;
        }
    }
```